# How to install gtkglextmm in Ubuntu LTS 14.04?

Tags: c++, opengl, mesa

Can you let me know the steps to install "gtkglextmm" in Ubuntu LTS 14.04? For learning experience, I am trying to compile basic examples from "gtkglextmm"?

According to the "README" file from "gtkglextmm", I would need the following.

## Requirements

- GNU C++ compiler
- GNU make
- GtkGLExt
- gtkmm 2
- GTK 2 (http://www.gtk.org/)
- OpenGL or Mesa (http://www.mesa3d.org/)
- Doxygen and Graphviz [optional]

Thank you.

Comment: We only support Ubutnu here. If you choose to ask question about other distros, the questions will get closed or downvoted.

Comment: I see. I thought programming questions might be okay. That is why I asked.